# Fetch adjacent column word?

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

I want condition like "if max(col1) then col2 end "in tableau calculated feild, output will be "e".
thanks in advance

Comment: What if two values are mapped with `c` in second column? Or are you sure that there will only be one such value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
If [col1] = {max([col1])} then col2 end
```

Drop this in view and Hide nulls, you'll get desired value.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it with these steps and it looks to be working :)

```
# first find the max. Using fixed lod calculation to do it across the whole dataset. The 1 is the same value across all so its doing a group max, but the group is the full data
MaxCol1: {fixed 1: MAX(Col1)}

# pick out rows where max is found in Col1
Col1Match: Col1=[MaxCol1]

# find Col2 where there's a match and fill rest with NULL's
Col2Value: IF [Col1Match] then Col2 else NULL end

# This will be a bunch of NULL's and "e"
# Finally, do the same as in the first calculation to get the result
Output: {fixed 1 : max([Col2Value])}
```

You can try combining some of these steps together now to clean up the space a bit. Does this suffice or is your real data more complicated?

Best,
Jonny